# How to get the difference of two multidimensional arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to get the difference of two multidimensional arrays, e.g.,

First Array:

```
Array
(
    [qtr_selected] => Array
        (
            [partner_q_m_p__2031] => Array
                (
                    [0] => q1
                    [1] => q2
                )

            [partner_q_m_p__2032] => Array
                (
                    [0] => q1
                )

        )

)
```

Second Array:

```
 Array
(
    [qtr_completed] => Array
        (
            [partner_q_m_p__2031] => Array
                (
                    [0] => q1
                )

        )

)
```

how do i get the difference of array1 & array2 as given below:

```
   Array
(
    [qtr_final] => Array
        (
            [partner_q_m_p__2031] => Array
                (
                    [0] => q2
                )

            [partner_q_m_p__2032] => Array
                (
                    [0] => q1
                )

        )

)
```

Tried array_diff() function but not getting  array1 as difference except array2, i want array1 after subtracting array2 from it.

Comment: How you get these arrays ? @kapil

Comment: i have stored the checkboxes data  in multidimensional arrays now i want to compare these arrays to get their difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply make a custom function like as

```
function check_diff($arr1, $arr2){
    $check = (is_array($arr1) && count($arr1)>0) ? true : false;
    $result = ($check) ? ((is_array($arr2) && count($arr2) > 0) ? $arr2 : array()) : array();
    if($check){
        foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
            if(isset($result[$key])){
                $result[$key] = array_diff($value,$result[$key]);
            }else{
                $result[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
$result['qtr_final'] = check_diff($a1['qtr_selected'],$a2['qtr_completed']);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: if first array is empty then still i am getting the value in final array, what i want is if first array is not present then it should not be in the final array.

Array
(
    [qtr_final] => Array
        (
            [partner_q_m_p__2031] => Array
                (
                    [0] => q1
                )

        )

)

Comment: i want to get not completed ones "qtr", i.e., if first array is not present then it should not be in the final array, second array holds completed qtr.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below :

```
$a1 = Array
(
        'qtr_selected' => Array
        (
                'partner_q_m_p__2031' => Array
                (
                        '0' => 'q1',
                        '1' => 'q2',
                ),

                'partner_q_m_p__2032' => Array
                (
                        '0' => 'q1'
                )

        )

);

$a2 = Array
(
        'qtr_completed' => Array
        (
                'partner_q_m_p__2031' => Array
                (
                        '0' => 'q1'
                )

        )

);

$result['qtr_final'] = check_diff_multi($a1['qtr_selected'], 

$a2['qtr_completed']);
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';


function check_diff_multi($array1, $array2){
    $result = array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
        if(isset($array2[$key])){
            if(is_array($val) && $array2[$key]){
                $result[$key] = check_diff_multi($val, $array2[$key]);
            }
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: AnkiiG , getting the result array as:


Array
(
    [qtr_final] => Array
        (
            [partner_q_m_p__2031] => Array
                (
                    [qtr_final] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => q2
                        )

                )

            [partner_q_m_p__2032] => Array
                (
                    [0] => q1
                )

        )

)


except of: 
            [partner_q_m_p__2031] => Array
                (
                    [1] => q2
                )

Comment: @kapil Please try now. I have updated. Thanks for pointing the issue

Comment: Thanks@AnkiiG your solution is also working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get difference of array1 and array2 by using this:

```
<?
// array 1
$array1['qtr_selected']['partner_q_m_p__2031'] = array('q1','q2');
$array1['qtr_selected']['partner_q_m_p__2032'] = array('q1');

// array 2
$array2['qtr_completed']['partner_q_m_p__2031'] = array('q1');

$removalArr = array();
foreach ($array2 as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
        $removalArr = $value2; // get last value of removal array
    }
}

$finalArr = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
        // check difference if available, 
        // if difference available use array_diff else use normal.
        $finalArr['qtr_final'][$key2] = (array_diff($value2,$removalArr) ? array_diff($value2,$removalArr) : $value2); 
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalArr);

?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [qtr_final] => Array
    (
        [partner_q_m_p__2031] => Array
        (
            [1] => q2
        )

        [partner_q_m_p__2032] => Array
        (
            [0] => q1
        )    
    )    
)
```